# Is it possible to get books author name value from href tag with Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" 
   href="/Cay-S.-Horstmann/e/B000AQ1QDY/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_1?qid=1542117551&amp;sr=8-1-spons">
    Cay S. Horstmann
</a>
```

What I mean is it possible to get *Cay S. Horstmann* text from above tag?

Now I'm trying to get it like this:

```
link.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal")).getText());
```

But it just outputs an empty string ...

```
public class AmazonSearchResultsPage {
    public AmazonSearchResultsPage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(css = "#s-results-list-atf")
    public WebElement searchResults;

    public void getBooksInfo () {
        List<WebElement> links = searchResults.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

        if (links.size() > 0) {
            String title, author, price, rating, isBestSeller;

            for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
                title = links.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector("h2.a-size-medium.s-inline.s-access-title.a-text-normal")).getText();
                author = links.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector("a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal")).getText());
            }
        }
        else System.out.println("Your search has no results");
    }
}
```

Update from comments

I'm trying to get books author name from searched books page on amazon.com, for example you can visit this link with search query "Java "amazon.com/s/… , I tried to get author name from there.

Comment: Try using getAttribute("value")

Comment: The output is null, not working.

Comment: Have you tried with other locators? _Eg: xpath: //a[contains(@href,'/Cay-S.-Horstmann/')]'_ also check there are no frames exist.

Comment: No luck. To be more specific, I'm trying to get books author name from searched books page on amazon.com, for example you can visit this link with search querry "Java "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Java&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3AJava , I tried to get author name from there. And what you mean by frames ?

Comment: Well, I am able to extract the author names from the url. I don't see a problem with the locator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question update to retrieve the *books author name* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired elements to be visible and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  List<WebElement> author_name_elements = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("ul#s-results-list-atf span.a-size-small.a-color-secondary>a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal")));
  for (WebElement author_name:author_name_elements){
      System.out.println(author_name.getText());
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  List<WebElement> author_name_elements = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']//span[contains(.,'by')]//following::span[1]/a[@class='a-link-normal a-text-normal']")));
  for (WebElement author_name:author_name_elements){
      System.out.println(author_name.getText());
  ```

Comment: DebanjanB, it really works ! I knew there must be some way to handle this, thank you )) I will accept your answer, but may be you can help me with Best Seller check also. I updated main post with the way I handled isBestSeller check, it works, but took too much time for check like this, may be a better way to handle this check exists ...

Comment: @Wonderio619 Glad to be able to help you !!! Can you please raise a new question with your new requirement? As there are multiple Answers available so changing the question will make the other answers **invalid** and may not be useful to future readers. For the time being I am reverting back your question to the previous state. StackOverflow contributers will be happy to help you out with your new question.

Comment: DebanjanB, I created a new thread here regarding remaining problems, please join if you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300695/some-troubles-with-gathering-information-from-website-using-selenium-java

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the URL I am able to extract the info.

```
@Test
    public static void testMF(){
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","./src/drivers/geckodriver64bit.exe");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Java&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3AJava");
        List<WebElement> authorNames=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/Cay-S.-Horstmann/')]"));
        for (WebElement author:authorNames){
            System.out.println(author.getText());
        }
    }
```

and here is the console output with the author name:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
1542125453774   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\Dhamo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.ZTVooPdHTxOZ"
1542125455373   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 63531
1542125455395   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Nov 13, 2018 10:10:55 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Cay S. Horstmann
Cay S. Horstmann
```

**Code for updated question:**

```
public static void testMF() {
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./src/drivers/geckodriver64bit.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get(
            "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Java&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3AJava");

    List<WebElement> searchResults = driver.findElements(By
            .xpath("//div[@class='s-item-container'][1]/div/div/div[@class='a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-right']"));
    System.out.println(searchResults.size());
    try {
        if (searchResults.size() > 0) {
            String title, author = null;
            int i = 0;
            for (WebElement el : searchResults) {
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", el);
                i++;
                title = el.findElement(By.cssSelector("h2.a-size-medium.s-inline.s-access-title.a-text-normal"))
                        .getText();
                System.out.println("Title:" + i + "-" + title);
                if(el.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.a-row.a-spacing-small > div:nth-child(2)")).size()>0){
                    author = el.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.a-row.a-spacing-small > div:nth-child(2)")).getText();
                }
                System.out.println("Author:" + i + "-" + (author.isEmpty()?"Author Not Found":author));
            }
        } else
            System.out.println("Your search has no results");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Dhamo, I got your point, but this is not exactly what I'm trying to do. I need to extract all authors names from search page. Not find author name by checking href. And you need to access href section and manually type author name for each search result for your code to work, this is not the way I want it to work. I updated main post with my code, I think you will understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Well, in that case, to extract all author names in the page, you need to change [to xpath:  //span[@class='a-size-small a-color-secondary' and contains(.,'by')]/../span[2]] the locator as the one you have is not only locating the author names but locating many elements in the page.

Comment: Dhamo, thank you, I will test your code tomorrow on internship, because my internet connection is very bad now. I see you used xpath for locating authors, is it somehow generated, or you write it using your own skills ? It is strange for me that I was not able to access simple linkText value from href by using cssselector, may be I should start learning xpath ...

Comment: I wrote it. Learning xpath is must. All the best!

Comment: Dhamo, unfortunately your code outputs Author:Cay S. Horstmann
Price:47 for every book on the page ...

Comment: @Wonderio619 - Please check the new code now . It is working.

Comment: I already got the answer for title and author part, if you want you can check my new question regarding other problems - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300695/some-troubles-with-gathering-information-from-website-using-selenium-java